# how to customize rss feed tags using hooks?

Tags: filters, hooks

My RSS feed is displaying an XML tag which I either want removed, or emptied. The tag in the XML looks like so:

`<wfw:commentRss>remove/this/uri</wfw:commentRss>`

I have never used hooks before but I know this can be done using them..

Any points in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the tag altogether would be inconvenient since it's hardcoded in [`feed-rss2.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.9/src/wp-includes/feed-rss2.php#L91) template file. You could replace the calling function in `do_feed_rss2` hook, but still would need to fork whole template.

It is, however, easy to cancel out content there. [`get_post_comments_feed_link()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_post_comments_feed_link/) passes output through the filter, so something like this should do it (not tested):

```
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', function() {
    add_filter( 'post_comments_feed_link', '__return_empty_string' );
}, 9);
```

Comment: This worked a treat, thanks! Would it be wise to separate the function out so it's not an anonymous function? And if so how would I do that? Thanks for your assistance Rarst :)

Comment: @Prefix as long as you don't do something crazy (like using PHP 5.2) you should be just fine :)